# How to Replace RC Formula Value with Variable

Tags: vba

I have the following lookup

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
       "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-4], 'C:\Users\me\Downloads\Ca%2f_client_vlookup\[" & myFileNameCA & "]" & mySheetNameCA & "'!R10C1:R112C7,1,FALSE),"""")"
```

How could I stored the value returned into variable ?

Comment: try with `WorksheetFunction.VLookup`...

Comment: I get an error here RC[-4] .. separator

Comment: oh no, it's not so easy. you need to search a bit on how to work with `Worksheetfunction.function()`... [link](http://www.exceltrick.com/formulas_macros/vlookup-in-vba/) or [link](http://www.cpearson.com/excel/callingworksheetfunctionsinvba.aspx)

Comment: to replace the `RC[-4]` you can use `ActiveCell.Column - 4`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
dim variable

variable = WorksheetFunction.VLOOKUP(RC[-4], 'C:\Users\me\Downloads\Ca%2f_client_vlookup\[" & myFileNameCA & "]" & mySheetNameCA & "'!R10C1:R112C7,1,FALSE)
```