# How to get VLOOKUP to select down to the lowest row in VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, automation, vlookup

Looking to automate the insertion of a VLOOKUP formula in a cell. 
When recording the macro I instruct it to populate the columns below with the same formula. Works great, however, there is an issue when the table that the VLOOKUP searches through changes (more or less rows).

As it's recorded, the VLOOKUP drops down to the final row in the table (273). However, I want to set it up so that it will go down to the very last row. Meaning that I can run the script on tables of varying numbers of rows.

Selected columns will remain the same.

```
Range("AJ2").Select
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
    "=VLOOKUP(RC[-20], Previous!R2C2:R273C22,17,FALSE)"
```

Comment: So basically  you want to find the last row of your table each time you write the formula to a cell? There are tons of postings on that. What have you tried searching?

Comment: Perhaps just use `Previous!C2:C22` instead of `Previous!R2C2:R273C22`?

Comment: @YowE3K: better not, since that will have VLOOKUP run on millions of rows!

Comment: @user3598756 - Judging by the speed in which it does it, I assumed Excel optimised VLookup to not look beyond the UsedRange.  (Or maybe even only look in non-empty areas?  I just tried sticking something on the first and last row and the VLookup was close to instanteous.)

Comment: I couldn't say about optimization, anyway as a good habit I always limit ranges extension to what actually needed

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
With Worksheets("Previous")
    Range("AJ2").FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=VLOOKUP(RC[-20], Previous!R2C2:R" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row & "C22,17,FALSE)"
End With
```

where:

- `Range("AJ2")`

  will implicitly reference the ActiveSheet
- `.Cells(.Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row`

  will reference "Previous" worksheet, being inside a `With Worksheets("Previous")- End With` block

Comment: @lookininward, did you get through it?

Comment: Had to get away and work on other issues. This is the one though, the last piece of the puzzle. Thanks for taking your time to help out.

Answer (score 1):

@nbayly said it, plenty of posts on this. Infact i have provided an answer to this before here:

[How to Replace RC Formula Value with Variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40378815/how-to-replace-rc-formula-value-with-variable/40379547#40379547)

below is slightly modified for a dynamic range, which is what i believe you are looking for

```
For j = n To 10 Step -1
    If Cells(j, 1).Value = "" Then
        Cells(j, 1).Formula = "=VLookup(RC20,Previous!R2C2:R273C22,17,FALSE)"
    End If
Next j
```

remember to define j as long and `n=sheets("sheetname)".cells(rows.count,1).end(xlup).row`

replace 10 in `j = n to 10 with the starting row number`