# assigning formula to variable range of rows VBA

Tags: vba, excel, macros, vlookup

I am trying to create a macro which dynamically performs a vlookup for a worksheet w/ a constantly increasing number of rows; I'd like to write the code so that it runs the vlookup from Q2 to the last populated row in col. Q (whatever that may be), and so far I have come up with this:

Range("Q2", Range("Q2").End(xlDown)).Value = "=VLOOKUP(A2,sheet2!A:BO,67,FALSE)"

..The macro performs everything it needs to do & changes accordingly for each row but it also runs infinitely down the column after there is no more data. I wanted to know if there's a way to do this in one line of code if possible. I'm sort of new to VBA & couldn't find an already-posted answer which sufficiently solved my problem so any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you search properly on the site? already answered pretty much the same question here: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40512439/how-to-get-vlookup-to-select-down-to-the-lowest-row-in-vba/40512623#40512623]. Adjust the R1C1 format to A1 format to fit your needs :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work according to the information you provided.  I'm guessing you are replacing an existing value with the formula otherwise the row lookup is going to return a value you don't want.  If you want the last row from another column just change the `Q` in `Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row` to the column you want.

```
Range("Q2:Q" & Cells(Rows.Count, "Q").End(xlUp).Row).Value = "=VLOOKUP(A2,sheet2!A:BO,67,FALSE)"
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply! however the code you provided only fills in cells Q1 and Q2. And no, I'm grabbing content for a new column so the vlookup will be filling in blank cells. Do you know how to start at Q2 and automatically fill in the Q column until the last row that has data in previous columns of the sheet?

Comment: What column do you want to gather the last row from?

Comment: Column A would probably be best as its the one I'm referencing for the vlookup

Comment: Just change the `Q` in `Cells(Rows.Count, "Q")` to an `A` like `Cells(Rows.Count, "A")`

Comment: ooooooh! Completely misunderstood what you meant by the last row from another column in your first comment. It works perfectly thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. Since you're new here, please don't forget to mark the answer accepted which helped most in solving the problem. See also [How does accepting an answer work?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work)