# Vlookup Macro 2 worksheets

Tags: vba, excel, macros

I am very new to VBA and any help will be appreciated. I am trying to create a macro to do a  vlookup instead of typing it in manually in the cell.

My excel file has 2 worksheets one called 'Microsoft' and the other called 'SN Username'.

So I am looking up data in 'SN Username' with the results of the lookup to return to sheet 'Microsoft' (B21)

Here is the vlookup im trying to do in VBA
=VLOOKUP(B21,'SN Username'!A:B,2,FALSE)

Any help would be grateful!
Thanks

Comment: Did you search the site properly? i have seen this question so many times now. Please refer to following link to assist you: [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40512439/how-to-get-vlookup-to-select-down-to-the-lowest-row-in-vba/40512623#40512623] :)

Comment: If I understand correctly, it sounds like you want the result of the vlookup to go in B21, but by passing B21 as a parameter you've got a circular reference. It would help if you post details of any errors or unexpected behaviour you get.

Comment: @Shah Miah you can use the VBA version of VLOOKUP with `Application.VLookup`, it depends what type of a solution fits your needs . Check my answer below and let me know if it works for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can the VBA version Function `Application.VLookup`.

The piece od code below checks if the value of Cell B21 in Sheet "Microsoft" is found in Columns A:B in Sheet "SN Username". If it's found it returns the second column to Cell A21 (you can modify it to your needs). If not, it puts in the cell A21 a text message of "Item Not Found" - just for reference.

```
Option Explicit

Sub VLookup_withErrHandling()

Dim Cell                As Range
Dim Rng                 As Range
Dim lRow                As Range

Set Cell = Sheets("Microsoft").Range("B21")
Set Rng = Sheets("SN Username").Range("A:B")

If Not IsError(Application.VLookup(Cell, Rng, 2, False)) Then
    Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = Application.VLookup(Cell, Rng, 2, False)
Else
    Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Item Not Found"
End If

End Sub
```

**Adding a `For` Loop**: in case you want to loop through many rows in your "Microsoft" sheet, you can add the piece of code below:

```
Dim lRow                As Long

' just for example, loop from row 21 until row 30
For lRow = 21 To 30
    Set Cell = Sheets("Microsoft").Range("B" & lRow)

    If Not IsError(Application.VLookup(Cell, Rng, 2, False)) Then
        Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = Application.VLookup(Cell, Rng, 2, False)
    Else
        Cell.Offset(0, -1).Value = "Item Not Found"
    End If

Next lRow
```

**Edit** 1: according to PO modified note below:

```
Option Explicit

Sub VLookup_withErrHandling()

Dim Cell                As Range
Dim Rng                 As Range
Dim LastRow             As Long
Dim lRow                As Long

With Sheets("SN Username")
    ' find last row with username in column A
    LastRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

    Set Rng = Sheets("SN Username").Range("A2:B" & LastRow)
End With

' loop through row 2 until row 20
For lRow = 2 To 20
    Set Cell = Sheets("Microsoft").Range("A" & lRow)

    If Not IsError(Application.VLookup(Cell.Value, Rng, 2, False)) Then
        Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Application.VLookup(Cell.Value, Rng, 2, False)
    Else
        Cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "UserName Not Found in SN UserNames sheet"
    End If

Next lRow

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Shai, Many thanks for your response! I am new to this so please bare with me.

Let me try explain this again as I think I may have not done previously.

Comment: Hi Shai, Many thanks for your response! I am new to this so please bare with me. 

Let me try explain this again (Apologies)

Sheet 'Microsoft' has a list of usernames in 'column A' (usernames starts at A2 and finish A20) 

Sheet 'SN Usernames' has the exact same username list in column A (usernames starts at A2 and finish A20) but also has a 'Full name' list in 'column B' (Full name starts at B2 and finish B20)

So what I am trying to do is Vlookup against the usernames and return the 'full name' value  in the 'Microsoft' worksheet in 'column B'

Comment: @ShahMiah try the code in my `Edit 1` section, it;s according to your latest expalnation of what you need

Comment: Hi Shai..This worked wonderfully! I cant thank you enough. I am now finally understanding codes bit by bit. Thanks you so Much